# Putting two generic Arrays into one Swift Dictionary with Generics

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I'm trying to put two different generic types into a collection. In this example there are two arrays, one containing `Int`s and the other `String`s.

```
let intArray = Array<Int>()
let stringArray = Array<String>()
let dict = [1:intArray, "one": stringArray]
```

The error reads **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.**

So I tried specifying the `Dictionary`'s type

```
let dict: [Hashable: Any] = [1:intArray, "one": stringArray]
```

This leads to two errors.

- **Using 'Hashable' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Hashable' is not supported.**
- **Protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements**

Adding `import Foundation` and using `NSDictionary` as the type works fine.

```
let dict: NSDictionary = [1:intArray, "one": stringArray]
```

But this should be possible in pure Swift too without using Foundation. What is the type the `Dictionary` has to have?

edit: This apparently has more to do with the type of the keys. They have to be of the same type, not just conform to `Hashable`.

```
let dict: [Int:Any] = [1:intArray, 2: stringArray]
```

This works. But is it possible to make the type of the value more precise? `[Int:Array<Any>]` does not work.

Comment: The root cause of this is that Hashable conforms to Equatable, and Equatable has the `==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self)` requirement which is what is behind "Protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements".

Comment: Also, you need `==` to resolve hash collisions, so this seems to be a valid complaint by the compiler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic dictionary value type in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736612/generic-dictionary-value-type-in-swift)

Comment: @AntonBronnikov The relevant (but probably duplicate) linked thread covers generic _values_ in a dictionary with same-type keys, whereas this covers both values and keys, where the latter (generic keys) is the more complex part. I realize that this threas is possibly, however, a duplicate of [the one I linked to in the end of my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119624/).

Comment: @dfri, sorry, you are right.  The OP's question is more broad.

Comment: The linked duplicate is a partial answer. I didn't realize it, but my question was about having multiple types as key and values for the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24737116/1542569) from @RobNapier, here is a similar approach that uses `enum` for both, keys and values of the dictionary:

```
enum Key: Equatable, Hashable {
    case IntKey(Int)
    case StringKey(String)

    var hashValue: Int {
        switch self {
        case .IntKey(let value)     : return 0.hashValue ^ value.hashValue
        case .StringKey(let value)  : return 1.hashValue ^ value.hashValue
        }
    }

    init(_ value: Int)    { self = .IntKey(value) }
    init(_ value: String) { self = .StringKey(value) }
}

func == (lhs: Key, rhs: Key) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.IntKey(let lhsValue),    .IntKey(let rhsValue))    : return lhsValue == rhsValue
    case (.StringKey(let lhsValue), .StringKey(let rhsValue)) : return lhsValue == rhsValue
    default: return false
    }
}

enum Value {
    case IntValue(Int)
    case StringValue(String)

    init(_ value: Int)    { self = .IntValue(value) }
    init(_ value: String) { self = .StringValue(value) }
}

var dict = [Key: Value]()

dict[Key(1)] = Value("One")
dict[Key(2)] = Value(2)
dict[Key("Three")] = Value("Three")
dict[Key("Four")] = Value(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the type the Dictionary has to have?

You may try:

```
let dict: [NSObject: Any] = [1: intArray, "one": stringArray]
```

---

The statement `let dict: [Hashable: Any] = ...` does not compile, because the type of the key of a `Dictionary` *must* be a *concrete* type conforming to `Hashable`, e.g. `Int`, `String`, etc. `Hashable` is not a concrete type.

The above suggestion works, because 1. `NSObject` is a concrete type (where you can instantiate objects from), 2. `NSObject` is a `Hashable`, and 3. because instances of subclasses of `NSObjects` will work here as well, and 4. the compiler can initialise `NSObject` subclasses from string and number literals.

If you don't like `NSObject` as the type of the key, you may create your own class or struct.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your first attempt `let dict = [1:intArray, "one": stringArray]` works if you include `Foundation`; yielding an `NSDictionary` (so no need to explicitly state this type).

The reason why we can have these kinds of, apparently, generic dictionaries when using `Foundation` is the implicit type conversion performed (behind the hood) by the compiler when bridging Swift native types to Foundation.

```
let intArray : [Int] = [10, 20, 30]
let stringArray : [String] = ["foo", "baz", "bar"]
let dict = [1:intArray, "onx": stringArray]

print(dict.dynamicType)
for e in dict {
    print(e.dynamicType, e.key.dynamicType, e.value.dynamicType)
}

/* __NSDictionaryI
   (AnyObject, AnyObject) __NSCFString _SwiftDeferredNSArray
   (AnyObject, AnyObject) __NSCFNumber _SwiftDeferredNSArray */
```

The keys as well as values in `dict` above are wrapped in type `AnyObject`; which can hold only reference (class) type objects; [the compiler implicitly performs conversion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) of value types `Int`/`String` to Foundation reference types `__NSCFNumber`/`__NSCFString`. This is still an `NSDictionary` though; e.g. `AnyObject` itself does not conform to `Hashable`, so it can't be used as a key in a native Swift dictionary.

---

If you wish to create Swift-native "generic-key" dictionary, I'd suggest you create a wrapper (say a structure) that conforms to `Hashable` and that wraps over the underlying (various) key type(s). See e.g. (the somewhat outdated) thread

- [How to create Dictionary that can hold anything in Key? or all the possible type it capable to hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119624/how-to-create-dictionary-that-can-hold-anything-in-key-or-all-the-possible-type)

Comment: Using Foundation and NSDictionary is already mentioned in my question.

Comment: @orkoden I mainly explained why the `NSDictionary` seemingly works "generically" on Swift native types, when it in fact performs implicit type conversions to reference type behind the hood; the last part of my answer (referring [to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119624/)) points to an existing thread for solving this with Swift:s native `Dictionary` type. AntonBronnikov:s solution solves this neatly though, glad he could help you out!