# Swift Dictionary With Expansive Type Constraints

Tags: swift, generics, dictionary

I would like to define a dictionary that allows multiple specific types for values. I can currently define a dictionary like this:

```
var foo = [String: String]
```

which constrains the value to one specific type

OR

```
var foo = [String: AnyObject]
```

which constrains the value to AnyObject, which is not particularly constrained.

I'd like to do something like:

```
var foo = [String: <String, Int>]
```

which would allow me to insert only strings or ints as values in this dictionary.

I've considered the use of an enum as seen here: [Generic dictionary value type in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736612/generic-dictionary-value-type-in-swift) but I would rather find a way that allows me to dynamically specify the types without expanding or creating a new enum.

```
var bar = [String: <String, Int, Bool, MyClass>]
```

It seems that I should be able to create a wrapper class with an internal dictionary of [String: AnyObject] that will allow for compile time type checking against an arbitrarily long list of classes that can be inserted.

```
class ECDictionary<T> {

    private var internal_storage = [String: AnyObject]()

    subscript(s: String) -> T {
        get {
            return internal_storage[s]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            internal_storage[s] = newValue
        }
    }
}


var myECDictionary = ECDictionary<String, Int, OtherClass>()
```

I could build this with runtime type checking, but I'd rather it be enforced at compile time. Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to a `Dictionary` where the value can be a `String`, an `Int`, a `Bool` or a `MyClass` you should

### Define your protocol

```
protocol MyDictionaryValue { }
```

### Conform String, Int, Bool and MyClass to MyDictionaryValue

```
extension String: MyDictionaryValue { }
extension Int: MyDictionaryValue { }
extension Bool: MyDictionaryValue { }
extension MyClass: MyDictionaryValue { }
```

### Declare your dictionary

```
var dict = [String:MyDictionaryValue]()
```

### Usage

```
dict["a"] = "a string"
dict["b"] = 1
dict["c"] = true
dict["d"] = MyClass()

dict["e"] = CGPointZero // error
dict["f"] = UIView() // error
```

Comment: Seems logical way to restrict Dictionary to have specific types

Comment: It is working in swift but i want to use this swift dictionary in objective c project it is not working @objc protocol not working

Comment: @objc public protocol MyDictionaryValue { }
extension String : MyDictionaryValue{}
error: Non-class type 'String' cannot conform to class protocol 'MyDictionaryValue'